# Java Callable and Future

Tags: java, callable

im working with Java Callable so i was writing a function that run a parrallel tasks, it's run perfectly for the first call but for the other call my function duplicate the number of iteration 
please some one can tell me where i was make mistake 
this is my code :

```
public void setInitialCost(List<Trajet> trajets) {
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    List<Future<Double>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Double>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < trajets.size(); i++) {

        Future<Double> future = executor.submit(new CallableCostCalculator(trajets.get(i).getPlannedTrips(), startPlanningView));
        futures.add(future);
        System.out.println("iteration" + i);

    }

    executor.shutdown();

    for (int j = 0; j < futures.size(); j++) {
        try {
            trajets.get(j).setCost(futures.get(j).get());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the result for 2 successif call :
   [image]

and I make call for my function from this controller :

```
@Autowired
RechercheTabouService rechercheTabouService;
@Autowired
PlannedTripService plannedTripService;

public void test() {
    System.out.println("start test");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse("12/11/2017");
        rechercheTabouService.setPlannedTrips(plannedTripService.findPlannedTripByDate(date, 1512127292, 200));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    rechercheTabouService.setInitialSolution();
    List<Trajet> initial = rechercheTabouService.getInitialSolution();
    rechercheTabouService.setInitialCost(initial);

    System.out.println("initial :" + rechercheTabouService.calculCostSolution(initial));

    @RequestMapping("/tabou")
    public Integer runtest () {
        test();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that calls the method `setInitialCost()`.

Comment: Sounds like you're not clearing the `trajets` parameter in between calls.

Comment: Georg  i was updating my post
Kayaman how i must clear the trajets can you explain more please